# How to create secure RPC Communication in .Net sample code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, rpc

Currently I am working on secure RPC communication, referring the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/which-security-provider-to-use. For RPC communication i have downloaded the code sample from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part-1. But here the communication is not encrypted. Could anyone share a sample code for encrypting RPC communication between server & client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try grpc (https://grpc.io/). it supports ssl

Comment: Thanks...I will try this out!